# How to close div that overlays the screen

Tags: javascript, html, gallery

In my web site I have a page where I put my photos. Now, I'm trying to create a JavaScript function that allows me to display a photo, clicked by the user, in a bigger scale. To do that, when the user clicks in one photo, the class "modal" which contains other version of the photo (not croped), appears. This part is working as expected. The problem appears when I'm trying to close that bigger image. Can someone help me, based on the code i already did? (It's for a university project and I would like to keep the code I already shown to the teacher).

```js
var imagens = document.getElementsByClassName("imagens");
for(var i=0; i<imagens.length; i++){
    imagens[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        //console.log(this.id);
        var splitedId = this.id.split("-");
        var IddivGrande = "grande-"+ splitedId[1];
        var imagemGrande = document.getElementById(IddivGrande);
        var modal = document.getElementById("modal");

        modal.style.display="block";
        imagemGrande.style.display="block";

       var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
       function clicar() {
            var botao = document.querySelector("span").click();
        }
        if(clicar) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    })
}
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    font-family: "Helvetica", serif;
}
/*main*/
article{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin-top:10%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}
h3{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
body>main>article>img{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin-top:10%;
}
#grande-01 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:4%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#grande-02 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:15%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#grande-03 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:20%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#grande-04 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#grande-05 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#grande-06 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#grande-07 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:65%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#grande-08 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:75%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#grande-09 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:85%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*tablet---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    article{
        width: 80%;
    }
    h3{
        font-size: 23px;
        left: 0;
        transform: none;
        margin-left: 1%;
    }
    body>main>article>img{
        display: inline-block;
        left: 0;
        transform: none;
        margin: 0 1%;
        margin-bottom: 5%;
    }
    #grande-01, #grande-02, #grande-03, #grande-04, #grande-05, #grande-06, #grande-07, #grande-08, #grande-09{
        top:50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    }
}
/*laptop----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    article{
        width: 90%;
    }
    h3{
        font-size: 25px;
        width: 350px;
    }
}
/*laptopL----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@media screen and (min-width: 1440px){
    h3{
        font-size: 30px;
        width: 400px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Portraits</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css_portraits.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <article>
        <h3>Portraits</h3>
        <img class="imagens"
             id="pequeno-01"
             srcset="imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Ines1_400.png 400w,
                                 imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Ines1_350.png 350w,
                                 imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Ines1_200.png 200w"
             sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 400px,
                                (min-width: 1024px) 350px,
                                 200px"
             src="imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Ines1_200.png" alt="Ines1">
        <img class="imagens"
             id="pequeno-02"
             srcset="imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Ines2_400.png 400w,
                                 imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Ines2_350.png 350w,
                                 imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Ines2_200.png 200w"
             sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 400px,
                                (min-width: 1024px) 350px,
                                 200px"
             src="imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Ines2_200.png" alt="Ines2">
        <img class="imagens"
             id="pequeno-03"
             srcset="imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Ines3_400.png 400w,
                                 imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Ines3_350.png 350w,
                                 imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Ines3_200.png 200w"
             sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 400px,
                                (min-width: 1024px) 350px,
                                 200px"
             src="imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Ines3_200.png" alt="Ines3">
        <img class="imagens"
             id="pequeno-04"
             srcset="imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Rafa1_400.png 400w,
                                 imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Rafa1_350.png 350w,
                                 imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Rafa1_200.png 200w"
             sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 400px,
                                (min-width: 1024px) 350px,
                                 200px"
             src="imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Rafa1_200.png" alt="Rafa1">
        <img class="imagens"
             id="pequeno-05"
             srcset="imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Rafa2_400.png 400w,
                                 imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Rafa2_350.png 350w,
                                 imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Rafa2_200.png 200w"
             sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 400px,
                                (min-width: 1024px) 350px,
                                 200px"
             src="imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Rafa2_200.png" alt="Rafa2">
        <img class="imagens"
             id="pequeno-06"
             srcset="imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Rafa3_400.png 400w,
                                 imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Rafa3_350.png 350w,
                                 imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Rafa3_200.png 200w"
             sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 400px,
                                (min-width: 1024px) 350px,
                                 200px"
             src="imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Rafa3_200.png" alt="Rafa3">
        <img class="imagens"
             id="pequeno-07"
             srcset="imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Sara1_400.png 400w,
                                 imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Sara1_350.png 350w,
                                 imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Sara1_200.png 200w"
             sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 400px,
                                (min-width: 1024px) 350px,
                                 200px"
             src="imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Sara1_200.png" alt="Sara1">
        <img class="imagens"
             id="pequeno-08"
             srcset="imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Sara2_400.png 400w,
                                 imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Sara2_350.png 350w,
                                 imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Sara2_200.png 200w"
             sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 400px,
                                (min-width: 1024px) 350px,
                                 200px"
             src="imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Sara2_200.png" alt="Sara2">
        <img class="imagens"
             id="pequeno-09"
             srcset="imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Sara3_400.png 400w,
                                 imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Sara3_350.png 350w,
                                 imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Sara3_200.png 200w"
             sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 400px,
                                (min-width: 1024px) 350px,
                                 200px"
             src="imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Sara3_200.png" alt="Sara3">

        <div class="modal" id="modal">
            <img id="grande-01"
                 srcset="imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Ines1_900.png 900w,
                         imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Ines1_600.png 600w,
                         imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Ines1_224.png 224w"
                 sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 900px,
                                (min-width: 768px) 600px,
                                 224px"
                 src="imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Ines1_224.png" alt="imagem_grande1">
            <img id="grande-02"
                 srcset="imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Ines2_900.png 900w,
                         imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Ines2_600.png 600w,
                         imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Ines2_224.png 224w"
                 sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 900px,
                                (min-width: 768px) 600px,
                                 224px"
                 src="imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Ines2_224.png" alt="imagem_grande2">
            <img id="grande-03"
                 srcset="imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Ines3_900.png 900w,
                         imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Ines3_600.png 600w,
                         imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Ines3_224.png 224w"
                 sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 900px,
                                (min-width: 768px) 600px,
                                 224px"
                 src="imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Ines3_224.png" alt="imagem_grande3">
            <img id="grande-04"
                 srcset="imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Rafa1_900.png 900w,
                         imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Rafa1_600.png 600w,
                         imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Rafa1_224.png 224w"
                 sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 900px,
                                (min-width: 768px) 600px,
                                 224px"
                 src="imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Rafa1_224.png" alt="imagem_grande4">
            <img id="grande-05"
                 srcset="imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Rafa2_900.png 900w,
                         imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Rafa2_600.png 600w,
                         imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Rafa2_224.png 224w"
                 sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 900px,
                                (min-width: 768px) 600px,
                                 224px"
                 src="imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Rafa2_224.png" alt="imagem_grande5">
            <img id="grande-06"
                 srcset="imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Rafa3_900.png 900w,
                         imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Rafa3_600.png 600w,
                         imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Rafa3_224.png 224w"
                 sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 900px,
                                (min-width: 768px) 600px,
                                 224px"
                 src="imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Rafa3_224.png" alt="imagem_grande6">
            <img id="grande-07"
                 srcset="imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Sara1_900.png 900w,
                         imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Sara1_600.png 600w,
                         imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Sara1_224.png 224w"
                 sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 900px,
                                (min-width: 768px) 600px,
                                 224px"
                 src="imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Sara2_224.png" alt="imagem_grande7">
            <img id="grande-08"
                 srcset="imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Sara2_900.png 900w,
                         imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Sara2_600.png 600w,
                         imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Sara2_224.png 224w"
                 sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 900px,
                                (min-width: 768px) 600px,
                                 224px"
                 src="imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Sara2_224.png" alt="imagem_grande8">
            <img id="grande-09"
                 srcset="imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Sara3_900.png 900w,
                         imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Sara3_600.png 600w,
                         imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Sara3_224.png 224w"
                 sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 900px,
                                (min-width: 768px) 600px,
                                 224px"
                 src="imagens/portraits/fotos_grandes/Sara3_224.png" alt="imagem_grande9">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
        </div>
    </article>
</main>
<script src="javaScript/js.js"></script>
<script src="javaScript/hamburguer.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function clicar() {
  var botao = document.querySelector("span").click();
}
if(clicar) {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

In above code, you are manually invoking the `click` event. Instead, add `click` listener. As well, passing function name within the `if` statement will always evaluates to truthy value.

Solution:

Add `click` listener to document, check if clicked element is `.close`, if yes then hide the `modal` else do not do anything.

```js
var imagens = document.getElementsByClassName("imagens");
for (var i = 0; i < imagens.length; i++) {
  imagens[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var splitedId = this.id.split("-");
    var IddivGrande = "grande-" + splitedId[1];
    var imagemGrande = document.getElementById(IddivGrande);
    var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
    modal.style.display = "block";
    imagemGrande.style.display = "block";
  });
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.close')) return;
  document.querySelector('#modal').style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    font-family: "Helvetica", serif;
}
/*main*/
article{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin-top:10%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}
h3{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
body>main>article>img{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin-top:10%;
}
#grande-01 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:4%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#grande-02 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:15%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#grande-03 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:20%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#grande-04 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#grande-05 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#grande-06 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#grande-07 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:65%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#grande-08 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:75%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#grande-09 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:85%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*tablet---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    article{
        width: 80%;
    }
    h3{
        font-size: 23px;
        left: 0;
        transform: none;
        margin-left: 1%;
    }
    body>main>article>img{
        display: inline-block;
        left: 0;
        transform: none;
        margin: 0 1%;
        margin-bottom: 5%;
    }
    #grande-01, #grande-02, #grande-03, #grande-04, #grande-05, #grande-06, #grande-07, #grande-08, #grande-09{
        top:50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    }
}
/*laptop----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    article{
        width: 90%;
    }
    h3{
        font-size: 25px;
        width: 350px;
    }
}
/*laptopL----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@media screen and (min-width: 1440px){
    h3{
        font-size: 30px;
        width: 400px;
    }
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h3>Portraits</h3>
  <img class="imagens" id="pequeno-01" srcset="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature,https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg" sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 400px,
                            (min-width: 1024px) 350px,
                             200px" src="imagens/portraits/fotos_quadradas/Ines1_200.png" alt="Ines1">

  <img class="imagens" id="pequeno-09" srcset="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature, https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg" sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 400px,
                            (min-width: 1024px) 350px,
                             200px" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" alt="Sara3">

  <div class="modal" id="modal">
    <img id="grande-01" srcset="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature 900w,
             https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg 600w" sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 900px,
                            (min-width: 768px) 600px,
                             224px" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" alt="imagem_grande1">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img id="grande-09" srcset="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature 900w,
             https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg 600w" sizes="(min-width: 1440px) 900px,
                            (min-width: 768px) 600px,
                             224px" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" alt="imagem_grande1">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
  </div>

</article>
```

-----Edit---

Instead of having all the images in the `modal` section, add only one `img` tag in `modal` and change it's src with the src of clicked img.

```js
const modal = document.getElementById('modal');

document.querySelectorAll('article > img').forEach(img => {
  img.addEventListener('click', function() {
    modal.querySelector('img').src = this.src;
    modal.style.display = "flex";
    modal.style.justifyContent = "center";
  });
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.close')) return;
  modal.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica", serif;
}


/*main*/

article {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

h3 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*tablet---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  article {
    width: 80%;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 23px;
    left: 0;
    transform: none;
    margin-left: 1%;
  }
  body>main>article>img {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    transform: none;
    margin: 0 1%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
  }
  #grande-01,
  #grande-02,
  #grande-03,
  #grande-04,
  #grande-05,
  #grande-06,
  #grande-07,
  #grande-08,
  #grande-09 {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  }
}


/*laptop----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  article {
    width: 90%;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 350px;
  }
}


/*laptopL----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
  h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 400px;
  }
}

article>img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h3>Portraits</h3>
  <img class="imagens" id="pequeno-01" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg" alt="Ines1">

  <img class="imagens" id="pequeno-09" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" alt="Sara3">

  <div class="modal" id="modal">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: It helped, but now when I click on an image, appears the image that I clicked and the image that I clicked before.